# Videojs original timeline not coming

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, video.js

I am using videojs in my application. I wrapped video tag inside video-wrapper div to make it as the size of parent div which is video-wrapper. But the problem is I am not able to see the actual timeline of videojs which comes with it. Chrome is adding it's own timeline I guess. This is my code

```
return (
            <div className="video-wrapper">
                <video id="example_video_1" controls preload="auto" className="video-js vjs-default-skin" data-setup='{"fluid":true}'>
                    <source src={videoSrc} type="video/mp4"/>
                </video>
            </div>)
```

and this is css

```
.video-wrapper {
        background: white;
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 50% ;
        /* 16:8 */
        padding-top: 25px;
        height: 0;
    }

    .video-wrapper > video {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

This is the result I get (look at the video timeline. It's not videojs's timeline)

[image]

This is how I want the player timeline to look like. Also it should fit in the video-wrapper. (In the below picture size is screwed up though)

[image]

The code for this was (but not responsive)

```
render() {
        var props = blacklist(this.props, 'children', 'className', 'src', 'type', 'onPlay');
        props.className = cx(this.props.className, 'videojs', 'video-js vjs-default-skin', 'vjs-big-play-centered');

        assign(props, {
            ref: 'video',
            controls: true,
            height:"650",
            width:"800"
        });

        if (this.props.tags.flag) {
            this.jumpToSpecificMarker();
            console.log("card clicked was" + this.props.card_Reducer.card_id);
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <video{... props}>
                    <source src={this.props.src} type="video/mp4"/>
                </video>

                {/*<button onClick={this.jumpToSpecificMarker.bind(this)}>next</button>*/}
                {/*<button onClick={this.prev.bind(this)}>prev</button>*/}
            </div>)

    }
```

Comment: have you checked video.js documentation? their example default example seems to be responsive, consider making your parent component responsive.

Comment: Yes. But where is it's code. And Isn't my component only responsive in the above code?

Comment: http://codepen.io/heff/pen/EarCt check this one.

Comment: Didn't get any code there

Comment: And why am I seeing that different timeline on videojs?